# Intermittent silent failures when receiving email

Tags: web-hosting, email

I’ve had a company host my website and email for the last six months or so and I’m having intermittent and silent failures where emails sent to me are not received.

- The sender never receives a “delivery notification failure” message.
- This has happened on multiple domains (@gmail.com, @microsoft.com)
- I’ve experienced it happening first hand when I sent a mail to myself
  from another account but I was unable to reproduce the error.
- It’s very rare (one in every 300 emails or so)
- The mails are not routed to my junk folder :)

Obviously I’m worried about the effect this has on my business – but what can I do? 
I don’t believe I have enough information to diagnose the problem (neither does my hosting company when I presented them with the same information) – should I switch to another host?

Comment: "happened on multiple domains" - from multiple _senders_? "I’ve experienced it happening first hand ... but I was unable to reproduce **the error**." - what error were you expecting? Mailservers on route, as well as your hosts, could be filtering it as spam? Is there anything unusual about the emails that get lost?

Comment: yes - from mulitple senders.
The error in this case was "the email I sent not showing up in my inbox".
There was nothing special about the emails that didn't make it.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly I think you can do nothing. It is more likely that this issue is a host problem and so they have to investigate on this. If they don't want to do so or you feel they don't really put efforts on this matter, just change the hosting company. In my experience this is not a common problem, so it will disappear switching to another hosting company.